# rsync with Cygwin creating weird directories

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to backup data from a local shared drive to a remove server. Both the local machine and the remote server are running Cygwin under Windows XP. I use the following command:

> rsync -aze ssh --size-only --delete //SharedFolder/dir/subdir user@remoteserver:/cygdrive/c/dir

The problem is that instead of copying files to the subdir directory, a new directory is created called subdir?, where ? is a non-ascii character. I tried various combinations of / at the end of the destination or remote path, always with the same result.

How can I tell rsync not to create this weird new directory?

Comment: What's the `?` character? `echo subdir* | od -t x1` should reveal this. I suspect a stray CR (\x0d), but I don't know what would be causing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the script file used to run the command was saved in the Windows format with \r\n line separators. That weird character was the carriage return. I saved the file in the unix format with just \n and things are now fine.